# Работа с клавиатурой в Jquery

Tags: jquery, клавиатура

Добрый день.

Хочу перехватывать нажатия клавиатуры.
Почему этот код выполняется много раз, а не 1?

```
$("body").on("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 38) {
        // up
       alert('1'); 
    }
    else if(e.keyCode === 40) {
        // down
       alert('2');      
    }      
 });
```

Comment: @Роман Ракзинб причина [не в этом фрагменте][1] кода. Ищите, где вы могли еще обрабатывать собятия нажатия клавиш.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/0zd7rpmq/

Comment: Это может быть связано,если вызвалось событие в дочернем элементе, а потом пошло по родительским пузырьковым методом или это бред?Тут привязка конкретно к body?

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, нет не бред. Для таких целей, используем e.stopPropagation() для остановки всплытия события к родительским элементам. [Смотрим][1].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/qcr6yLf0/1/

Comment: Пример понятен,но всёравно то же самое